# Creating a mini-game about guessing

Tags: batch-file

So I'm programming a mini-game about writing an id code, and then letting someone guess it. The problem i am facing, is that whenever someone tries to change the font color using the game syntax, just shows an error: "( was unexpected at this time." and just instantly crashes. This is my code at the moment:

```
@echo off
cls
:play
set /p id=Identification code: 

if %id% == color:0 (
    color 0
    cls
    goto play

) else if %id% == color:a (
    color a
    cls
    goto play

) else if %id% == color:b (
    color b
    cls
    goto play

) else if %id% == color:c (
    color c
    cls
    goto play

) else if %id% == color:d (
    color d
    cls
    goto play

) else if %id% == color:e (
    color e
    cls
    goto play

) else if %id% == color:f (
    color f
    cls
    goto play

) else (
    cls
    echo Identification stored.
    pause
    cls
    set /p conf=Enter identification: 

    if %conf% == %id% (
        cls
        echo Access granted.
        pause
        exit

    ) else if %conf% == #cheat.code:(acss_grnt.admn)$ (
        color c
        cls
        echo Cheating system..
        timeout 3 >nul
        tree
        dir
        timeout 1 >nul
        cls
        echo Access granted.
        pause
        exit

    else (
        cls
        echo Access denied.
        pause
        exit
    )
```

Comment: If you're learning programming, I would *highly* suggest choosing a different language. Python is a much, much, much better choice and is even easier to use.

Comment: I am currently learning python, just having some fun :)

Comment: Please use `IF /I "%variable%"=="string"`, _(both sides with double quotes)_. I included the `/I` option for case insensitivity, type `IF /?` for information.

Comment: Nope, still the same error. :(

Comment: @Yoshix, It wasn't an answer it was advice by way of comment.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks much bud :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be aware from `COLOR /?` "Color attributes are specified by TWO hex digits"; you are just using one. You have not added any code to determine what the current foreground colour is. "The COLOR command sets ERRORLEVEL to 1 if an attempt is made to execute the COLOR command with a foreground and background color that are the same". Don't assume the foreground color attribute, if you're assuming it is currently `8` then add `8` after the background attribute in your `COLOR` commands.

You do not need to use all those `ELSE IF` combinations:

```bat
@ECHO OFF

:PLAY
SET/P "ID=Identification code: "

IF /I "%ID%"=="color:0" (
    COLOR 08
    GOTO PLAY
)
IF /I "%ID%"=="color:a" (
    COLOR A8
    GOTO PLAY
)
IF /I "%ID%"=="color:b" (
    COLOR B8
    GOTO PLAY
)
IF /I "%ID%"=="color:c" (
    COLOR C8
    GOTO PLAY
)
IF /I "%ID%"=="color:d" (
    COLOR D8
    GOTO PLAY
)
IF /I "%ID%"=="color:e" (
    COLOR E8
    GOTO PLAY
)
IF /I "%ID%"=="color:f" (
    COLOR F8
    GOTO PLAY
)
```

I have removed all of those `CLS` commands, just begin `:PLAY` with `CLS` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! Actually, the thing about that foreground color, I only wanted the text color. And the cls commands are there to clean the window from the color command. :)

Comment: Wait, but now the only thing working is the color:0 -> color:e. I can't get anything else to work :(

Comment: To change the text colour you'd need to reverse the hex digits, e.g.`COLOR 8E` - _grey background with light yellow text_.

Comment: I know, but anytime i want to actually write an id, I just keep getting an error message: "if was not expected this time."

Comment: Theres a stack overflow question on google i found that talked about how you cant use colon in a variable name unless you go through a process.  Do you think that might br helpful?

Comment: No, thanks. :) I already fixed it. Wouldn't do it thanks to you guys. ;)

Comment: The snippet I provided should work fine, what I want to know is exactly what would you like the end user to guess in order to move forward to the next stage of the 'game'

Comment: I don't really know haha :) I'm mainly doing this for practice.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing parenthesis for this block :

```
else if %conf% == #cheat.code:(acss_grnt.admn)$ (
        color c
        cls
        echo Cheating system..
        timeout 3 >nul
        tree
        dir
        timeout 1 >nul
        cls
        echo Access granted.
        pause
        exit
```

You are also missing a closing parenthesis for this else block :

```
else (
    cls
    echo Identification stored.
    pause
    cls
    set /p conf=Enter identification:
```

Comment: Does it say which line its having an issue with?

Comment: I think you have to replace each "else if" block with "else ( if (  ..... ) ) " blocks....I think the ELSE IF syntax is not right. If this does help you, can you mark it as the answer so that someone else searching for the answer might find it.

Comment: No, sorry. The "else if" syntax is correct, since i checked it before i even bothered with making this game. The problem is the "if" command. And no, it doesn't say which line it is :(

Comment: Oh no. I will take a second look. Sorry.

Comment: I cant find any resource describing this kind of use : color:0. I think this might be an issue. Its flagging the ( because thats right after that statement. Can you describe what color:0 does for example?

Comment: Yeah, it's meant to change the color for it's default (gray). I realised and changed "color 0" to "color". The color:0 is the "color" command for the games syntax, since you can't define variables with spaces. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to keep the structure simple computers/programs are there to avoid tiresome repetitions so the color thing is put in one logical line with a line continuation char `^` at the end and using conditional execution on success `&&` or fail `||` of the result of the findstring.
I don't know if I could always follow your logic, so try it out.

```
@echo off
Set "Wait=timeout /T 3 /nobreak>NUL"
:play
cls
set "id="
set /p id=Identification code: 
If "%id%"=="" Echo no input&timeout 3>NUL&goto play

IF /i "%id:~0,6%"=="color:" Echo:%id%|findstr /I "^color:[0a-f]$" >NUL 2>&1 ^
   &&(color %id:~-1%&Goto play)||(Echo wrong color&%Wait%&goto play)

cls
echo Identification stored.
%Wait%
cls
set "conf="
set /p conf=Enter identification: 

if "%conf%"=="%id%" (
  cls
  echo Access granted.
  %Wait%
  exit
) else if /i "%conf%"=="#cheat.code:(acss_grnt.admn)$" (
  color c&cls&echo Cheating system..
  %Wait%
  tree&dir
  timeout 1 >nul
  cls&echo Access granted.
  %Wait%
  exit
)
cls&echo Access denied.
%Wait%
exit
```

Comment: Works, but too complicated for me xD. Fixed it tho :)